# Build login,registration system with php and mysql for android,but app can run

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, xml

I currently work with an login and registration system for android app.I use mysql as database,php to doing that,but after doing all the system files,the app just stop when clicking to login button..pls help,below is all the code i made

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/images" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:text="Plot Out"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:text="Bring Me Out"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:width="100sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:text="Register"
            android:width="100sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/link_to_forgotpassword"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Forgot Your Password?"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="#ffffff">

       <!--  Header Starts-->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip" >

        <!-- Logo Start-->
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
        <!-- Logo Ends -->
</LinearLayout>
<!--  Header Ends -->

       <!-- Footer Start -->
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dip"
    android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</LinearLayout>
<!-- Footer Ends -->

        <!-- Login Form -->
        <LinearLayout

          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="10dip"
          android:layout_below="@id/header">
          <!--  Email Label -->
          <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/loginEmail"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="Email"/>
          <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:singleLine="true" />

          <!--  Password Label -->
          <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="Password"/>

          <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:password="true"/>

           <!--  Error message -->
        <TextView android:id="@+id/login_error"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#e30000"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

          <!-- Login button -->
          <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:text="Login"/>
          <!-- Link to Registration Screen -->

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/link_to_register"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
              android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:text="New to Plot Out?Register here"
              android:textColor="#0b84aa"
              android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
<!-- Login Form Ends -->

  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

register.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#fff">

        <!--  Header  Starts-->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="5dip">
                <!-- Logo Start-->
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
                <!-- Logo Ends -->
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--  Header Ends -->
        <!-- Footer Start -->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="90dip"
                android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Footer Ends -->

        <!-- Registration Form -->
        <!-- Registration Form Ends -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Full Name"
                android:textColor="#372c24" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/registerName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textColor="#372c24" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/registerEmail"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Password"
                android:textColor="#372c24" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/registerPassword"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:password="true"
                android:singleLine="true" />

           <!--  Error message -->
        <TextView android:id="@+id/register_error"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#e30000"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:text="Register New Account" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/link_to_login"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Already has account! Login here"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.plotout.loginandregister;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.plotout.loginandregister.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.plotout.loginandregister.library.UserFunctions;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnLogin;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView loginErrorMsg;
    TextView link_to_register;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        link_to_register = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.link_to_register);
        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(dashboard);

                            // Close Login Screen
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // Error in login
                            loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_login);

        // Listening to register new account link
        registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Switching to Register screen
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

RegisterAvtivity.java

```
package com.plotout.loginandregister;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.plotout.loginandregister.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.plotout.loginandregister.library.UserFunctions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnRegister;
    TextView link_to_login;
    EditText inputFullName;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView registerErrorMsg;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        link_to_login= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_login);
        registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

        // Register Button Click event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);

                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            // user successfully registred
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        
                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(dashboard);
                            // Close Registration Screen
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // Error in registration
                            registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        TextView loginScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_login);

        // Listening to Login Screen link
        loginScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                // Closing registration screen
                // Switching to Login Screen/closing register screen
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Below is the logcat shown in ecplise
 [image: a busy cat]

i just change the id of edit text in login xml,is solve the ClassCastException error..
<

```
EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/loginEmail"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:singleLine="true" />
```

Now is become a new error,  "java.lang.NullPointerException"..So where is the reason again ya??

All experts here pls take a look ya.pls help..thank you

Comment: huh, Where is the logcat?

Comment: This is a typical problem that you are doing networking stuff on UI thread. Use `AsyncTask` for doing connection with your server.

Comment: The error in your logcat show classCastExemption, try cleaning your project and rebuild it.

Comment: so what should i do now??

Comment: which part i should build again??

Comment: Clean your whole project And see if the error still occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button doesn't do anything because the following two lines in `LoginActivity` throw a `ClassCastException` because you can't cast from an `Android.widget.TextView` to an `Android.widget.EditView`.

```
inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
```

In `main.xml` change the first two `<TextView ... />` to `<EditText ... />` :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    ...
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Change to :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    ...
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: Check your xml, I did not noticed that. He is right, in your xml it is Textview while in your java code it is EditText. Edit that and your problem will be gone

Comment: or need to build new public void to cast the edit text??

Comment: i solve the logcat ady..but it become the another new error.."java.lang.NullPointerException"..

Comment: @ken edit your question and add the new error, along with updating the code.

Comment: @JonnyHenly sir i just update the question ady,along with the new error..tq

Comment: @JonnyHenly  Just look back my past question.Now I understand what you saying..haha..Just realized how silly I am in the past.haha